# What do you call a girl having big eyes?

Tags: synonyms

I am trying to describe a big-eyed girl. I was not getting a proper phrase in English to describe her eyes. What is the proper one-word phrase for the big-eyed girl in English? The title looks odd when I write " The Boy who loved big-eyed girl". Is there some attractive phrase?

big-eyed girl 
ball-eyed girl

Comment: I think it's usual to use a postmodifying phrase (usually a with-phrase), probably as this sounds less in-your-face.

Comment: As @EdwinAshworth implies, you would have to say 'the girl with big (or large) eyes'. Oddly enough, we describe people as 'blue-eyed', 'brown-eyed' or even 'one-eyed', but 'big-eyed' is not a common expression.

Comment: Do you mean https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wide-eyed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Doe-eyed

> Doe-eyed is defined as someone who has an innocent, wide-eyed look. A naive girl with big eyes who looks at you for answers is an example of someone who is doe-eyed.

[Source](https://www.yourdictionary.com/doe-eyed)

Note: this is diffeeent from *bambi-eyes*, which is an expression someone makes when they want to get their way.

Answer (score 0):

You could say she has **anime eyes**.

[image: Alita still]

[James Cameron's 'Alita: Battle Angel' stars creepy CG anime eyes](https://www.engadget.com/2017/12/08/james-cameron-alita-trailer/)

Answer (score 0):

As you have sensed, the form **adjective-eyed** or even **animal-eyed** generates quite a few results in English. Here are several related to size, from the [Oxford English Dictionary's Historical Thesaurus](https://oed.com/view/th/class/25912) for "the world > life > the body > external parts of body > head > face > eye >  [adjective] > by size, shape, etc. > having (51)"

- Goggle-eyed (older, emphasis on staring)
- Great-eyed (large or prominent, also perceptive)
- Large-eyed (large)
- Full-eyed (full, large, or wide)
- Broad-eyed (wide)
- Ox-eyed (large, round, protuberant)
- Saucer-eyed (wide, esp. in fear)
- Wide-eyed (wide, esp. in surprise)
- Moon-eyed (large, wide)
- Big-eyed (large)
- Pop-eyed (bulging, prominent, esp. in amazement)
- Bug-eyed (wide, bulging, esp. in fear or surprise)

Some suggest emotions (saucer-eyed, wide-eyed, bug-eyed). Others are used fairly generally and neutrally (big-eyed, large-eyed). To a certain extent, you can also form other words with this format, if the noun or adjective you pick would make sense with **-eyed**:

- cow-eyed (oh, [it exists](https://www.google.com/search?q=cow-eyed&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-e))
- horse-eyed ([it exists](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-e&ei=075mXYvgAaG-ggek_a7wDA&q=horse-eyed&oq=horse-eyed&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30l2j0j0i7i30l6j0i30.17040.17597..17708...0.3..0.77.357.5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.Hokby643krw&ved=0ahUKEwjLlf6pkKbkAhUhn-AKHaS-C84Q4dUDCAo&uact=5))
- bowl-eyed ([it exists](https://books.google.com/books?id=W2KeFGuBQdEC&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=bowl-eyed&source=bl&ots=SiDtrZXxY5&sig=ACfU3U3-eU7Vp67HvRCEgt8SBB-WqeFCHQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5me3HkKbkAhXuY98KHZetDr04FBDoATAGegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=bowl-eyed&f=false))
- huge-eyed ([it exists](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-e&ei=Vr9mXaOjHq-l_Qaw_4eICg&q=%22huge-eyed%22&oq=%22huge-eyed%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30l7j0i10i30j0i30l2.2138.2915..3190...0.2..0.77.141.2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.0ViKE_BPW5Q&ved=0ahUKEwijptbokKbkAhWvUt8KHbD_AaEQ4dUDCAo&uact=5))

When writing, attractiveness will be in the eye of the beholder. Someone who loves horses might find horse-eyes attractive. Someone who likes the moon might find moon-eyes swell. So if it seems like I've left some ugly eyes in here, it's only to not put limits on what your narrator might find attractive.

Comment: Now I want to write Van Morrison parodies for all these eyes.